# Getting session of an opened process using SSH

Tags: ssh, mplayer

Let me explain my question using an example. Suppose i am playing a song in terminal using mplayer command. It will start playing and i can see the playback statistics. Is there any way to get that same playing statistics session through SSH ing to that server?

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for might be "process output" or "stdout".

The usual way of doing this is to run mplayer in a tool like `tmux`, `screen`, or `dtach`, which actually create detachable "sessions"; then attach over SSH to the same tmux session.

Comment: I know it can be achieved using screen. But It is not using any screen. Can i access the stdout ?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: Not what it has already output, no. But you can try "moving" it using `reptyr`, so that it'll start outputting to the tty of your SSH connection. (Works most of the time, but not 100%.)